# Is there a word/phrase for the relationship between my parent and my parent-in-law?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

When my mother introduces my mother-in-law, she would say "This is ___". I know English hasn't many relationship terms, so is it just "This is my daughter-in-law's mum"?

Comment: Does your language have a term for it? And if so what is it? I don't know any such term in my own language, hence the curiosity.

Comment: Regardless of differences in "generations", they're all just ***in-laws***. Anglophones don't care about "familial relationship terminology" as much as speakers of many other languages.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337, yes in Chinese.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 German has a term ("Gegenschwieger", literally "opposite in-law") too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English does not have such a word. Your mother would say: "This is Judy, my daughter's mother-in-law", or "This is Judy -- she's the mother of my son-in-law Bill."

There are [terms in Yiddish and Hebrew](https://www.thejc.com/judaism/jewish-words/machatonim-1.8109), which *might* be used by older American Jews (such as my mother, who is in her 80s and the daughter of immigrants):

- machatonister (for the mother-in-law of your child)
- mechuten (for the father-in-law of your child)
- machatonim (plural)

The "ch" is pronounced in the back of the throat, as in German. Unlike [other Yiddish words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Yiddish_origin), these have not been imported into English, and few Americans of any religious background would know them.

Comment: +1 Gevalt, I haven't heard _mechuten_ in 50 years! Far afield from English, but well remembered.